# Select element which matches specific element in subtree but not another element in subtree

Tags: css, unpoly

Unpoly adds a class `up-loading` on targets currently loading.
I want to use that to display a loading spinner.

I don't want a spinner on exactly that element because the target could be a scrollable element (like big tables). Instead I'm adding a wrapper element somewhere above the tree to mark this element to be used for the spinner as soon as `up-loading` is coming up down the line.

I already have a selector selecting an element that does contain `up-loading` down the tree: `.up-loading-spinner:has(.up-loading)`
This works fine (except FF) but my main problem is that there could be another loading element in the tree which should have the same logic but with this I get the spinner displayed multiply times :/

This works fine:

```
<div class="up-loading-spinner">
    <div class="up-loading">...</div>
</div>
```

but this shows the spinner twice where I want to have them on lowest level only:

```
<div class="up-loading-spinner">
    ...
    <div class="up-loading-spinner">
        <div class="overflow-auto">
            <table class="up-loading">...</table>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Any ideas how to prevent the spinner showing twice?
And how to make it work in FF?

I would like to do in in plain CSS without JavaScript.